# Probability of a $\max$ number of an array of Uniform rv's being higher than $x$

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Recently I faced this question

> Let $U_1, U_2, U_3$ all come from a uniform$(0,1)$ distribution. Let $M = \max(U_1, U_2, U_3)$. Estimate (to $3$ significant digits) the probability of $M > 0.75$.

So as a started, I started taking baby steps.

At first, I thought if I only had one value, and for that the probability would be $0.25\%$. Then I thought abut the addition rule and I figured this couldn't be right, as if I had $4$ elements the probability would be $100\%$, which is not correct. By reading the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), I couldn't think of how I could apply it with this question as well.

How should I approach this question in order to fully understand and solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the $U_i$'s are independent.

1. Step 1: Make sure that you understand the following equivalence (if and only if statement) $$\max{\{U_1,U_2,U_3\}}\le 0.75\iff U_1\le 0.75,\;U_2\le 0.75,\;U_3\le 0.75$$ (the LHS implies the RHS and vice versa, can you see this?). This implies that 
   $$\Pr\left(\max{\{U_1,U_2,U_3\}}\le 0.75\right)=\Pr\left(U_1\le 0.75,\;U_2\le 0.75,\;U_3\le 0.75\right)$$
2. Step 2: The rv's $U_1, U_2, U_3$ have the same distribution which you can denote with $U$ (ok, this is pretty much a trivial step), so you can write the previous relation as $$\Pr(M\le 0.75)=\Pr(U\le 0.75)^3=0.75^3=0.422$$ But you want the probability of the *complementary event $M>0.75$* hence $$0.422=\Pr(M\le 0.75)=1-\Pr(M>0.75)\implies \Pr(M>0.75)=0.578$$

Comment: You explained it very clearly, I understood the concept. This was basically logical thinking. Thanks!

Comment: However I must ask, shouldn't your equivalence in step 1 be Higher-than rather than Lower-than?

Comment: First check that it holds as it is. If the $\max$ is less than $0.75$ then each is one is less than $0.75$, and if each one is less than $0.75$ then their $\max$ is less than $0.75$. So, the statement holds, LHS and RHS are equivalent. If we replace with $\ge$ in both sides, then it is not true anymore. The $\max$ can be $\ge 0.75$ but this does not imply that each one is $\ge 0.75$. However, the other implication holds: If each one is $\ge 0.75$ then the $\max$ is also $\ge 0.75$ but this is not enough for the LHS and RHS to be now equivalent.

Comment: Awww can't believe I didn't see this before! Thanks!

Comment: @user2018675 It is really not easy to see this, when you deal with it for the first time!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If the $U_i$ are supposed to be independent, you can calculate
$$\begin{align*}P(M > 0.75) = &1 - P(M \le 0.75) = 1 - P(U_1 \le 0.75, U_2 \le 0.75, U_3 \le 0.75)\\
 =&1 - P(U_1 \le 0.75) P(U_2 \le 0.75)P(U_3 \le 0.75)\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

$P(M>=0.75)=1-P(M<0.75)$
$P(M<0.75)=P(U_1<0.75,U_2<0.75,U_3<0.75)$, indeed , if the maximum is smaller than 0.75, so are all of them , and reciprocally .

Assuming they are mutually independent,

$ P(U_1<0.75,U_2<0.75,U_3<0.75)=P(U_1<0.75)P(U_2<0.75)P(U_3<0.75)$
$=P(U_1<0.75)^3$
$=0.75^3$